# Joomla 3 Widgetkit not showing in component menu

Tags: database, joomla, menu, widget, components

I have installed and added a lot of data in my Joomla 3 Yoo Widgetkit, but I found out that it should be a widgetkit menu item in components menu, but it is not. I googled and found this solution:

Go into the YOURDBPREFIX_menu ( eg: dfde_menus ) and find the entry for the widgetkit and delete that entry using the delete command in your Database Tools, like phpMyAdmin . After you have done that, try to reinstall the latest versions of WidgetKit.

but I don't want to delete all my data I have added in widgetkit, so can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but in my YOURDBPREFIX_menu was no menu item for the widgetkit. So, I inserted one manually and after that I installed the widgetkit once more and this worked out for me.

This is my MySQL code:

```
INSERT INTO `YOURDBPREFIX_menu` (`id`, `menutype`, `title`, `alias`, `note`, `path`, `link`, `type`, `published`, `parent_id`, `level`, `component_id`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `browserNav`, `access`, `img`, `template_style_id`, `params`, `lft`, `rgt`, `home`, `language`, `client_id`) VALUES (133, 'main', 'COM_WIDGETKIT', 'com-widgetkit', '', 'com-widgetkit', 'index.php?option=com_widgetkit', 'component', 0, 1, 1, 10029, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 1, 'components/com_widgetkit/images/widgetkit_16.png', 0, '', 111, 112, 0, '', 1);
```

You might need to change the '133', because this needs to be a unique id code.
And change the YOURDBPREFIX in the correct prefix of course.

Comment: I reinstalled my widgetkit and but still it doesn't show in Component Menu, here is what it looks like in db: 115  main  COM_WIDGETKIT  com_widgetkit     com_widgetkit  index.php?option=com_widgetkit  component  0  1  1  10006  0  0000-00-00 00:00:00  0  1  components/com_widgetkit/images/widgetkit_16.png  0     71  72  0     1

Comment: @Irakli: Was the entry already there in the database? Or did you enter it? In my case the entry was not there. I don't know about the procedure when the entry was already there.